# How to add quote marks to string in Sublime?

Tags: sublimetext3

In Sublime text editor, I have a text as below (taking notes for nodejs in markdown format)

> In Nodejs, command-line arguments will be stored in the process object and in the process object there is a property called argv(argument vector) and arguments will be stored in the form of array

If I want to search all `process` words and add markdown back-ticks quotes(`) around them, How can I do this in sublime ?

Comment: Single quote (`'`) or back-tick (`\``)? Back-ticks are used to define in-line code.

Comment: @theTinMan, back-tik quotes I mean to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are no places where the string "process" is in the middle of a word, such as "subprocess", I would do:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> to open search.
2. Enter `process` in the search field.
3. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to select all coincidences.
4. Edit accordingly.

If I wanted to check each coincidence to avoid adding the quote marks erroneously I would instead do:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> to open search and replace.
2. Enter `process` in the search field.
3. Enter `` `process` `` in the replace field.
4. Click Find to see the next coincidence.
5. Click Replace or Find as necessary.

Comment: `<Shift>+<Cmd>+F` is Find and Replace on Mac OS.